# React JS - How to detect navigator.platform in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, navigator

I'm writing a small function in Next JS with react. When I use navigator, I get the following error.

`ReferenceError: navigator is not defined`

Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {

const isMac = navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf("MAC") >= 0;

  return (
   {isMac ? "I'm mac" : "I'm windows"}
  );
}
```

How do I get browser platform and then render a section based on that?

Comment: Of course the very first question here should be: "why?" because there is almost nothing that requires knowing the OS, and browsers are 100% allowed to lie about anything and everything in the navigator object, because `navigator` contains a wealth of data that can be used by tracking companies to fingerprint you so they can track you across all websites.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I got that point, but incase I need to run that and show something based on that, how would I do it. Searched for more than an hour.. but no solution found.

Comment: The short answer is "you don't", browsers don't have to tell you what OS they run on, so you can't rely on having that information. You could try to properly namespace your call, so `window.navigator` or `globalThis.navigator`, but both of those can be shadowed so you're still not guaranteed anything.

Comment: I got it, but this is just for UI purpose. Its okay if browser given wrong info. 
But my problem is it does not work at all. I'm not sure where should I write the code.

Comment: No, you're not listening: many properties of navigator are not even guaranteed to exist, so you _cannot rely on them_, even if you want to use them "just for UI purposes". You are guaranteed to frequently run into the fact that it won't be there, so don't write code around it being there. `Navigator` is an ancient and mostly deprecated object, and you should probably check the [MDN article for Navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Navigator). For `navigator.platform`, we see that (1) it's deprecated, and (2) the text "Do not rely on this function to return a significant value".

Comment: `if (process.browser) console.log(window.navigator)`

Comment: @PunitMakwana how do I get that data in to the render function?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have checked with other client functions like "window.innerwidth" etc. In that case, how would I get the data and pass it to render() ?

Comment: That's a completely different question that has nothing to do with navigator.platform, or even OS detection (all that tells you is how wide the current page's content pane is). If you just want to know how to access data in `render()` in React/Next, there plenty of questions and answers on SO already that you can search for just fine, but more importantly: that is fundamental to how it works, so is definitely covered by the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, this is what I need to write.

```js
const isMac = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf("MAC") >= 0 : false;
```

Comment: Can we detect Windows OS? and Mobile, Android, IOS, Browser type?